# How to locate an element with preceding-sibling?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
<a href="/pro/2/len.html" class="lol-link" href="/pro/2/len.html"> <span hide="trololo"> <img class="prod" ng-src="https://med.png" alt="Len" src="https://med.png"> </span> <span ng-hide="index" class="ng-hide"> <span>Len</span> </span> </a>
```

My xpath:

```
"//span[contains(text(), 'Len')]/preceding-sibling::span"
```

i want to locate text 'Len' but unfortunately my xpath doesn't work. Could somebody help?

Comment: Looks like `//span[.='Len']` to me, but perhaps there's something you haven't told us?

Comment: or `//a[@class="lol-link"]/span[2]/span`,may be there is more going on before this hyperlink.

Comment: @simpleApp, @MichaelKay Doesn't work. I tried `//span[contains(@class,'ng-hide')]/preceding-sibling::span` and it works, but I don't know how to get to 'Len'

Comment: I want to locate text 'Len'  but on what condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

`//span[span="Len"]/span`